# Skip job if PR number in array

Tags: github-actions

My GitHub Actions workflow is supposed to run when a pull request is created or updated, *unless* the PR number is on a (hardcoded) deny list.

For example, if the deny list is just "5, 7", this works fine:

```
name: My-Workflow
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  build:
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number != 5 && github.event.pull_request.number != 7 }}
```

This isn't particularly practical though if the deny list grows to, let's say, 10-20 PR numbers. So I'm looking for a way to provide a (hardcoded) array.

Something like this:

```
name: My-Workflow
on:
  pull_request:
env:
  DENY_LIST: "[5,7,9,12,18,25]"
jobs:
  build:
    if: ${{ !contains(fromJSON(env.DENY_LIST), github.event.pull_request.number) }}
```

Sadly, this does *not* work because GitHub Actions [does not yet support using environment variables on the job level](https://github.community/t/how-to-set-and-access-a-workflow-variable/17335) (hard to believe this hasn't been fixed yet).

Hardcoding the array in the `if` expression, like this...

```
    if: ${{ !contains([5,7,9,12,18,25]), github.event.pull_request.number) }}
```

... doesn't work either- looks like [literals](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#literals) can't be arrays.

This...

```
    if: ${{ !contains(fromJSON("[5,7,9,12,18,25]"), github.event.pull_request.number) }}
```

... doesn't work either ("Unexpected symbol").

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about using a label for these PRs, say `ci-skip`?

Comment: Good idea! I'd still be curious if there's a way to do it with an array (since that could also come handy for other things).

Comment: Did you try the `contains` function? (reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contains)

Comment: Right there in the question! :)

Comment: Use one job to compute if the PR is eligble with bash or another scripting language of your choice and set an output for this job. Use this output in the second job's `if` to determine if it should be run.

Comment: Also you must use single quotes for strings. Does changing double quotes in  `fromJSON("[5,7,9,12,18,25]")` to single quotes help?